# Drupal 7 "admin" pages inherit front-end theme CSS

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-themes

I am trying not to effect the styling of the Drupal 7 admin pages with my sub-theme CSS files. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably have the same theme the admin interface and your site. You have to set a different theme for the administration interface on `http://yoursite/admin/appearance`

Comment: This was not the case in my particular situation. The Administration Theme was set to a theme titled "Seven" (which is different from my front-end theme). But, your answer lead me to a checkbox on the admin/appearance page, "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" and checking this box solved my problem. Thanks!